# Good file manager replacement in Linux / Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, gnome, windows-explorer

I like to use Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) and I'm constantly disappointed at the lack of power in the file managers.

What uber-powerful all inclusive awesomesauce solution do you use?

/yes, I know about the terminal
//yes, I'm lazy

Comment: This should be moved to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Old questions can't be migrated. Otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) to the rescue!

[image: screenshot]

I don't use it anymore actually, but I do remember using the dos-version, and knowing all the hotkeys... I could really do things a lot faster!
I even remember still using that old dos-version under windows 3.11 because it was so much better than the windows explorer.

**Edit**: Just been searching, and it was actually Norton Commander which I used in dos (from which total commander is a clone):

[image: another screenshot]

Comment: My GOD, that's ugly.  It must be awesome.

Comment: It grows on you over the time. You'll learn to love it!

Answer (score 1):

[sunflower-fm](https://code.google.com/p/sunflower-fm/) is a GNOME file manager currently in alpha. I just started reading about it on reddit this morning but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

An old fart replies: I use the old File Manager from Windows NT4 (or was it 3.51?). It dosn't have the right clickery that Explorer does, but it's much faster, much better at file copies and file deletes and doesn't hang up every time a network drive won't reconnect.

I've tried just about every File Manager replacement out there but they're all just too slow or too fussy to use. Mind you my idea of anawesomesauce solution is the command prompt :-)

Not a solution for unix of course.

JR

Answer (score 0):

[midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) is very good and highly tweakable. It is also very light and is perfect for remote ssh session as it is console based.

Comment: -1, The link is broken firstly. Also the Windows Port of Midnight Commander is BETA. I wouldn't trust it on Windows yet.

Answer (score 0):

xplorer2 is good, however I'm still looking for a file browser that integrates with the run dialog for easy launching.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be talking about Orthodox file managers.  [Nikolai Bezroukov has a whole WWW site about them](http://softpanorama.org./OFM/index.shtml), that includes some user commentary.

Answer (score -1):

i like to open rox filer windows from the terminal